# unit element in cohomology and k-theory

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory

It is some well-known fact that there is the unit element in $K^{-2}(point)$ whereas there is no unit in $H^{-2}(point)$? Where it is come from?

For details I add the link http://pages.uoregon.edu/ddugger/kgeom.pdf , the last lines of the page 169. The author fixes this fact in the way that I also don't understand. Can anyone explain what is going on there?

Comment: $H^{-2}$ is always zero. As for $K$-theory see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bott+element.

Comment: what means the notation $H^{*}[t,t^{-1}]$? what do square brackets are for?

Comment: The square brackets are used to denote a polynomial ring in the indiccated variables https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring . A class in $H^*(X)[t,t^{-1}]$ is a finite polynomial $\Sigma_{i=-n,\dots, n} t^{-i}x_i$, where each $x_i\in H^*(X)$ is a (possibly trivial) cohomology class.

Comment: How from that conclude that for $*=0$ we have $H^{ev}(X)=\oplus_{i}H^{2i}(X)$?